# Express Nodemon not ending jobs after saving the project and reloading the server

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

Every time I save my project with the server on this same error

```
> yarn dev         //start server here ok!
yarn run v1.21.1
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ nodemon src/server.js
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node -r sucrase/register src/server.js`  // Save the server 
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node -r sucrase/register src/server.js`
events.js:183                                                // error
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/tuliocaz/Projects/bootcamp/fastfeet/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tuliocaz/Projects/bootcamp/fastfeet/backend/src/server.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/tuliocaz/Projects/bootcamp/fastfeet/backend/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/tuliocaz/Projects/bootcamp/fastfeet/backend/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

scripts I'm running:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "dev:debug": "nodemon --inspect src/server.js",
    "queue": "nodemon src/queue.js"
```

Archive nodemon.json:

```
{
  "execMap": {
    "js": "node -r sucrase/register"
  }
}
```

My OS is Ubuntu

So I'm forced to close all jobs on ports 5000 where the server is running

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show us the content of the `yarn dev` script. With the output alone it's hard to pinpoint where the problem lies.

Comment: @thomaux added archives